# Least Prime Ideal in Chebotarev density theorem, in function fields.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, function-fields

For every finite extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, for every finite Galois extension $L$ of $K$ and every conjugacy class $\mathcal{C}$ of Gal$(L/K)$, there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$ that is unramified in $L$  and

$$ \bigg[ \frac{L/K}{\mathfrak{p}} \bigg] = \mathcal{C}$$ as wella as $$ N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\mathfrak{p})$$ is a rational prime satisfying $$N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\mathfrak{p}) \leq |d_{L}|^{12577}\hspace{2mm}.$$

This is the state of the art bound for the least prime ideal in the Chebotarev density theorem I found in [this paper](https://aif.centre-mersenne.org/item/?id=AIF_2019__69_3_1411_0). There are works that prove that under GRH one can improve the upper bound $|d_{L}|^{12577}$ above to $c \cdot log|d_{L}|$ for some constant $c$.

The Riemann hypothesis for function fields $\mathbb{F}_{q}(T)$, where $q$ is some prime power, is already known. However, I could not find equivalent result about least prime ideal in the Chebotarev density theorem in function fields, despite wide searching.

Has the analogous result already been done or is too trivial in the latter case? If already done, can anyone explain the result and/or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you looked in the chapter on the Chebotarev density theorem in Fried and Jarden's book *Field Arithmetic*?

Comment: I did , after seeing your comment. There are versions of Chebotarev density theorem with error terms. However, I don't think there is any referring to the least ideal in the theorem. At the end of the chapter, they do refer that Lagarias et al have the result for least ideal in the theorem for number fields, but again not for function fields.

Comment: The recent paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.06201 is on Chebotarev in short intervals in $\mathbb F_q(T)$.  That does not answer your question, since they are concerned with asymptotic statements about short intervals, but I suspect a nonempty subset of the four authors should know a reference that answers the question you asked. When you do get an answer, you can post it as an answer to your own question if someone else doesn't do that first.